# How to instrument Akka actors?

Tags: akka, metrics

We are working on an internal project, and besides not being experts in Akka, we are more like playing around with routers and dispatchers configurations, and supervisors. Given that our app handles loads of requests, we want to measure how our configuration changes affects the app performance. We know about some commercial tools to do monitoring on Akka, but we want to go first with some in-house work like using Codehale's Metrics. Does anybody know about a simple strategy to instrument Akka actors by using something like Metrics?, also we don't want to do this live, we want to get some reports after a stress test on a controlled env.

Thanks!

Comment: This is kind of a broad question.  You need to figure out what kinds of metrics you want and maybe articulate that here first.  I've done something similar to what you are asking, using Metrics and creating an instrumented mailbox impl.  This was to give me an idea of how much time on average a message spends in the mailbox before hitting the `receive` method, but this is just one example of a metric you could collect.  Figure out what you want first and then update your post and I'll see if I can provide more detail for you.

Comment: Just as a note, we've had a lot of problems with the typesafe console in terms of performance and configuration. It's not very mature at the time of writing from our experience.

Comment: We're looking for the same thing.  I was considering having a base actor class that would time invocations etc of he onReceive method, but I would like more that this, like a general stat of the system for example

Answer (score 0):

If you are ready to dive into akka sources you can instrument/intercept some core methods in actor and dispatcher implementations (using AspectJ for example) and gather any stats you wish, thats stats can be visible via jmx.